# How to optimally turn a multidimentional list into a single list of items in Python?

Tags: python, list, optimization, recursion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Input a list such as: [1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7,[8]]],[9],10]

Desired output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Currently I have the following recursive function:

```
def fix_list( li , l = [] ):
    for i in li:
        try:
            len( i )
            fix_list( i, l )
        except:
            l.append( i )
    return l
```

I feel like the try/except catch is a little gimmicky and slow, and I'm wondering if there is a better/more optimized way to perform this task. All input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also try if type(i) == type(1).

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: It is very easy once you figure it out to see how slow (or not) your function is with the timeit module.

Comment: I like this question because the answers illustrate a good use of generators rather than returning a whole new list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative version (originally inspired by Artsiom Rudzenka's) that modifies the list in place using slice assignment rather than creating a new list on each pass. Interestingly, only one pass through the list is needed!  My use of `enumerate()` is a little unorthodox; I use it to keep track of an index into a list that may be growing as I iterate over it, but don't actually use the actual list item.

```
def flattened(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):

    items = items[:]  # we will return a copy; remove to mutate original
    for i, _ in enumerate(items):
        while isinstance(items[i], seqtypes):
            items[i:i+1] = items[i]
    return items

print flattened([1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7,[8]]],[9],10])
```

Generator version:

```
def flattener(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):

    items = items[:]
    for i, _ in enumerate(items):
        while isinstance(items[i], seqtypes):
            items[i:i+1] = items[i]
        yield items[i]

print list(flattener([1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7,[8]]],[9],10]))
```

Here is a `list` subclass that has a `flatten()` method.  Like the `sort()` and `reverse()` methods, this mutates the list and returns `None`.

```
class listy(list):

    def flatten(self, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):
        for i, _ in enumerate(self):
            while isinstance(self[i], seqtypes):
                self[i:i+1] = self[i]

lst = listy([1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7,[8]]],[9],10])
lst.flatten()
print lst
```

Edit: I simplified this pretty significantly from my original version. However, I see the question has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python/2158532#2158532):

```
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
```

Comment: @Gandi: Well at least I said where I got it, senderle didn't.

Comment: I don't say there's anything wrong in it.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should post it as an aswer IMHO; but rather note that it is a duplicate of another question.

Comment: @nightcracker, I wrote it in the process of trying to understand how to create a recursive generator :). Eerily similar, though, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple generator that does this:

```
def flatten(nested):
    for item in nested:
        if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(item, basestring):
            for inner_item in flatten(item):
                yield inner_item
        else:
            yield item
```

Not sure whether it's "optimal" or not.

Comment: Did you just copy that solution and rename variables so its your own?

Comment: @phant0m, no, I copied it from a script that I wrote a while ago trying to understand recursive generators. I'm unsettled by its similarity to the one nightcracker posted though.

Comment: Mine looks exactly the same, except when checking for an iterable I use hasattr(el, '\_\_iter\_\_'). The rest is practically identical. Anyone spending 15 minutes on this will come to more or less the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried solution below and it works:

```
data = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7,[8]]],[9],10]

while any(isinstance(x, list) for x in data):
    tmpLst = []
    for x in data:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            tmpLst.extend(x)
        else:
            tmpLst.append(x)
    data = tmpLst
```

Comment: Why make a copy of `tmpLst` at the end of the loop?

Comment: @kindall - i am modifying initial list in order to have ability to leave while loop.

Comment: yes, but it seems to me that `data = tmpLst` would work fine, without using the slice/copy, since `tmpLst` is already a copy of the original list.

Comment: Have tried it and yes - seems that you are right(i simply use it with [:] in order to not get an error with shallow/deep copy).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach ..

```
def flatten(old, new):                                                                                                                      
    for i in old:                                                                                                                           
        flatten(i, new) if isinstance(i, list) else new.append(i)                                                                           
    return new                                                                                                                              

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                  
    l1 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, 7, [8]]], [9], 10]                                                                                            
    l2 = list()                                                                                                                             
    l3 = flatten(l1, l2)                                                                                                                     
    print l3
```

Simplified so you don't have to supply and empty list to the flatten argument list ..

```
def rec_flatten(old, new=list()):                                                                                                           
    for i in old:                                                                                                                           
        rec_flatten(i, new) if isinstance(i, list) else new.append(i)                                                                       
    return new                                                                                                                              

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                  
    l1 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, 7, [8]]], [9], 10]                                                                                            
    x = rec_flatten(l1)                                                                                                                     
    print x
```

Comment: Your second version will accumulate multiple lists; try calling it a few times in a single script.